# validator: onSuccess to return true or false not excuting

Tags: javascript, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to have function validation return true or false on success and on error which is being requested by another function, in order to show save confirmation modal or not on Error but its not returning anything or not even executing once return line is read. Validate function does not seem to return anything.
If someone could help me please.

validate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    $('#enableForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            required: 'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk',
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstname: {
                selector:'#firstName',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },

            lastname: {
                    selector:'#lastName',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },

            birthdate: {
                selector:'#birthDate',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The birth date is required and cannot be empty'               
                    },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',   
                        message: 'The value is not a valid date'
                    }   
                }
            }                
        },
        onSuccess:function () {
            return true;                        
        },
        onError: function(){
            return false;
        }
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Click function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#savePatient').click(function(event){
        if (validate()){
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = this;
        window.setTimeout(function(form){
            $(form).submit();
            $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
        }, 1500, $(button).closest('form'));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
<title>Patients Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
            <div id="includedLogout"></div>
                <h1>Patients</h1>
                <p>Patient Profile</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
        <form:form id="enableForm" commandName="patient" class="form-horizontal">
                <legend>Add Patients</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="firstName" path="firstName" type="text"/></div>
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="middleIni">Middle Initial</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="middleIni" path="middleIni" type="text"/></div>
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs"  id="lastName" path="lastName" type="text"/></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="address">Address</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="address" path="address" type="text"/></div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 comp-xs" for="middleIni">Apt No. | Suite No. | Unit No.</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="address2" path="address2" type="text"/></div>                 
                </div>      

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="city">City</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="city" path="city" type="text"/></div>
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="state">State</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-1"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" id="state" path="state" type="text"/></div>
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="zipCode">Zip Code</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"><form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs"  id="zipCode" path="zipCode" type="text"/></div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-1 comp-xs" for="birthDate">Birth Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <fmt:formatDate var="fmtDate" value="${patient.birthDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>                       
                    <form:input cssClass="form-control comp-xs" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" id="birthDate" path="birthDate" value="${fmtDate}" type="text" class="form:input-large"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="submit" id="savePatient" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value ="Save" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header modal-header-saved">
                             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <h1><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Data Saved</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
        </form:form>
    </div>
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedLogout").load("logout.jsp");  
      $("#includedContent").load("navbar.jsp"); 
    });
    </script> 
/body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
  @Arkni placed the validator inside the $(document).ready(...) used the following code below but modal keeps looping and showing and hiding and form is not submitting. Thank you again for your help.

```
    onSuccess: function (e) {
            // Stop form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#modal-1').modal('show');

            window.setTimeout(function(form) {
                $(form).submit();
                $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
            }, 1500, $('#savePatient').closest('form'));
        }
```

Comment: is `bootstrapValidator` an async function?

Comment: To be honest I'm sorry I have no clue. I'm new to all this, trying to learn I did try for a few hours to figure it out but I couldn't. :(

Comment: @Oaen, why don't you put your code inside the `onSuccess` handler ?

Comment: One other question: `#savePatient` is it a submit button or just a normal one ?

Comment: Thanks Arkni. #savePatient is a submit button. I tried to place the modal.show at the onSuccess function but it get stuck in a loop of showing and hiding the modal. document on ready function is also calling validate i'll try to play with it.

Comment: @Oaen see my answer bellow.

Comment: @Arkni I was clicking the arrow key up and down I must have clicked on it. I'm  really a newbie, and it's embarrassing sorry. I un-checked it :D

Comment: @Oaen it's ok :), can you add the HTML markup to your question, so i can create a simple example for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before proceeding in solving the problem, you have to know that:

1. According to [jQuery Events: Stop (Mis)Using Return False](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), returning false inside an event handler performs three tasks when called:

   - *`event.preventDefault();`*
   - *`event.stopPropagation();`*
   - Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.
2. Returning `true` inside an event handler will not stop event propagation, but Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

---

I suggest you to use one of the following solutions instead of `$('#savePatient').click(function(event){ ... });` and `function validate() { ... }`:

**# Solution 1: Using the *`onSucess`* handler**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            excluded: ':disabled',
            feedbackIcons: {
                // ...
            },
            fields: {
                // ...
            },
            onSuccess: function (e) {
                // Stop form submission
                e.preventDefault();

                $('#modal-1').modal('show');

                window.setTimeout(function(form) {
                    $(form).submit();
                    $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
                }, 1500, $('#savePatient').closest('form'));
            }
        });
});
```

**# Solution 2: Using the event *`success.form.bv`***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            excluded: ':disabled',
            feedbackIcons: {
                // ...
            },
            fields: {
                // ...
            }
        })
        // This event triggered when the form is valid
        // It's the equivalent to using the `onSuccess` handler
        .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#modal-1').modal('show');

            window.setTimeout(function(form) {
                $(form).submit();
                $('#modal-1').modal('hide');
            }, 1500, $('#savePatient').closest('form'));
        });
});
```

**# Working example:**

As I can see, you are using Spring MVC, that's why I used the rendered HTML markup in order to create a demo, see http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/kxxua2f7/

---

**# UPDATE 2015-07-28**

To fix the problem you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644722/validator-onsuccess-to-return-true-or-false-not-excuting/31665834?noredirect=1#comment51281106_31665834), use the *`group`* option.

The `group` option: is a CSS selector indicates the parent element of field. By default, it is `.form-group`.
In your case, the parent of ***`firstname`*** and ***`lastname`*** is the div that have the class `.col-sm-2`, see the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#enableForm')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                // ...
            },
            fields: {
                firstname: {
                    selector: '#firstName',
                    group: '.col-sm-2', // <===== USE THIS OPTION
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                lastname: {
                    selector: '#lastName',
                    group: '.col-sm-2', // <===== USE THIS OPTION
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                        }
                    }
                },
                birthdate: {
                    // ...
                }
            },
            onSuccess: function (e) {
                // ...
            }
        });
});
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/kxxua2f7/2/

Comment: Thanks Arkni so much.  I tried putting it in. And when I tried it modal keeps on looping showing and hiding. and page is not submitting. Not sure why this happened to me yesterday when i placed it in the bootstrapvalidator function itself.                                                                                                                            code below

Comment: As in my answer, I suggest to remove the function `validate()`, and do all that inside the `$(document).ready( ... );`

Comment: If you can add to your question (edit it) the HTML markup, I can then create an example for you.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Arkni!!! It led me to find more about the submit() and i read an article about document.getElementById(..).submit(); and it worked!!! But, now I noticed that when I Type on my required input fields it defaults to red invalid theme with a check as too supposed to be green with a check mark. It also does it in your fiddle. why is that? should I start a new thread?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate sharing the explanation behind answer. It educates me and the people who may maybe looking for answer regarding the same question. Again Thank you. :D